# Dynamically invoke properties by string name using VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, reflection, invoke

I'm currently working on a project where a section of the code looks like this:

```
Select Case oReader.Name
    Case "NameExample1"
        Me.Elements.NameExample1.Value = oReader.ReadString
        ' ...
    Case "NameExampleN"
        Me.Elements.NameExampleN.Value = oReader.ReadString
        ' ...
End Select
```

It continues on for a while. The code is obviously verbose and it *feels* like it could be improved. Is there any way to dynamically invoke a property in VB.NET such that something like this can be done:

```
Dim sReadString As String = oReader.ReadString
Me.Elements.InvokeProperty(sReadString).Value = sReadString
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Others have answered perfectly reasonably, but just in case this is a performance-sensitive piece of code, you might want to compile the reflective calls into delegates.

I've got a [blog entry](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2008/08/09/making-reflection-fly-and-exploring-delegates) about turning [MethodBase.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodbase.invoke.aspx) into delegates. The code is in C#, but the same technique can be applied to VB.NET as well. To use this with properties, get the appropriate "setter" method with [PropertyInfo.GetSetMethod](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.getsetmethod.aspx) and then build a delegate which invokes that. You could have a map from field name to "delegate to call to set the field".

Just to reiterate, this is only really necessary if it's in a performance-critical piece of code. Otherwise, you might still want to create a `Dictionary<string, PropertyInfo>` to avoid calling `GetProperty` many times, but the step to convert it into a delegate probably isn't worth worrying about.

Comment: CallByName looks simpler. How does this differ from Reflection in terms of performance?

Comment: I believe CallByName uses Reflection internally, and I suspect applies various VB-specific shenanigans for backward compatibility. Test it, but I very much doubt that you'll see it being as fast as a delegate. Yes, using MakeDelegate is more complicated, but vastly more performant than reflection.

Comment: your blog entry link is broken

Answer (score 32):

I can't believe the other posters told you to use reflection. VB as a [CallByName](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.callbyname?view=netcore-3.1) function that does exactly what you want.

Comment: Holy crap, I wish I knew about this years ago.

Comment: This is a great quick and dirty method for simple/small use cases. I wouldn't use this for anything complex or where you have lots of 'work' unless performance is not a concern.

Comment: If performance is a concern, you should use runtime code generation instead of reflection.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, CallByName is the best solution for you. Here's instruction of doing it:

```
CallByName(yourClassOrObjectName,"NameExample1",CallType.Set,oReader.ReadString)
```

You can write "NameExample" in place of "NameExample1".
Mention, that third parameter lets you 'Get', 'Let' that parameter (and even invoke any method).
So you can get your parameter's value using `CallType.Get`.