# Better way to populate form fields from SQL?

Tags: .net, asp.net, vb.net, class, webforms

I am trying to populate a web from from a SQL table.

This is what I have right now, though I am not sure if it's the best way to do things, please give me suggestions:

```
Public Class userDetails
    Public address1 As String
    Public address2 As String
    Public city As String
    ...
...
...
End Class

Public Class clsPerson
    'set SQL connection
    Dim objFormat As New clsFormat
    Dim objConn As New clsConn()
    Dim connStr As String = objConn.getConn()
    Dim myConnection As New Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(connStr)

    Public Function GetPersonDetails() As userDetails
        'connection and all other good stuff here

        Try
            ' Execute the command
            myConnection.Open()
            dr = myCommand.ExecuteReader()

            ' Make sure a record was returned
            If dr.Read() Then
                ' Create and Populate ApplicantDetails
                userDetails.address1 = dr("address1")
                userDetails.address2 = objFormat.CheckNull(dr("address2"))
                userDetails.city = objFormat.CheckNull(dr("city"))
                ....

            Else
                Err.Raise(4938, "clsUser", "Error in GetUserDetails - User Not Found")
            End If

            dr.Close()
        Finally
            myConnection.Close()
        End Try

        Return userDetails
    End Function
```

i then use GetPersonDetails() function in my backend to populate the form.

like so:

```
Dim userDetails as new userDetails
userdetails = getPersonDetails()

txtAddress.text = userdetails.address1

etc....
```

however, there are like 50 fields in the User db, and it seems like a lot of retyping... please help me find a better way to do this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. [Reflect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240836/dynamically-invoke-properties-by-string-name-using-vb-net) the property names
2. Infer the controlname from the property name, e.g., "txt" & fieldName
3. Use [FindControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx) to find the control and populate its Text property.

You could also generate the fields dynamically, though you lose some control over the presentation. This is a solution I wouldn't use, however - it will tend to make the code brittle and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Data Binding is something that is used to help move data between your form and your database.  Basically you map a form field to a database field and can control if it refreshes in one direction(readonly) or both directions(read/write).  You will probably still have a statement mapping each field, but it makes things easier sometimes.  It is one of those things that gets much more complicated if you try to do anything more than the basics, but it can almost always be adapted because it is very modular, allowing you to modify the behavior or implement your own classes/interfaces to build solutions for more complex scenarios.

Notice there is a "Continue Reading" link at the bottom:
http://www.startvbdotnet.com/ado/simplebinding.aspx