# VB.NET - Access variable in class within class by string name

Tags: vb.net, reflection

So here is part of my class structure:

```
Public Class CParticle

    Public Feature As Double
    Public AreaName As String
    ......  

    Public ElementsWT As SElements      'Elements in wt%
    Public ElementsAT As SElements      'Elements in at%

    Public Sub New()

        ElementsWT = New SElements
        ElementsAT = New SElements

    End Sub

End Class
```

With this 'subclass':

```
Public Class SElements

    Public B As Double
    Public C As Double
    Public N As Double
    Public O As Double
    Public F As Double
    ....

End Class
```

Now I want to access all variables within an instance of CParticle (e.g. called 'Particle') and also its instances of SElements by their name (String).

e.g.: "Feature" should give me access to Particle.Feature

Currently im doing it with reflection:

```
...
Dim myFieldInfo As FieldInfo

myFieldInfo = GetType(CParticle).GetField("Feature")
If Not myFieldInfo Is Nothing Then myFieldInfo.SetValue(Particle, value)
```

This works. But how can I access e.g. Particle.ElementsWT.B with the string "ElementsWT.B"? And is there an overall better way to do it besides using reflection?

Comment: Can you please tell us why you want to use a string instead of directly accessing the objects? Is the caller code in another dll? Anyway, you could use two dictionaries, one in  SElements and one in CParticle with key: fieldName value: object. Fill it in the constructor manually or via reflection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically invoke properties by string name using VB.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240836/dynamically-invoke-properties-by-string-name-using-vb-net)

Comment: You are right @Alex B., I'd prefer a Dictionary so that reflection is only called once upon creation of the instance. Maybe stupid additional question, as im cycling through the fields in my class, how do i get he reference to the object itself? The name is clear: 'field.Name'

Comment: I don´t know if I understood you correctly but the `Me` keyword gives you the current instance of th object in scope